# Oracle with Clients: I must install oracle for client?

Tags: oracle, client

I'm very newbie for Oracle and very not sure about Oracle.
one question I want to know.

if I want develop oracle windows application. first I must install oracle on server for database server but I'm not sure if I don't want install oracle on client. I must install oracle for client YES or NO !?

thank for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  The Oracle client must be installed on any machine wishing to access the database.  The components of the client you need to install will depend on the method your application using.  eg. OLEDB, ODBC, etc.

Comment: If you access Oracle with a Java application using the "thin" driver, no Client installation is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is 'it depends' - your software will need some kind of client-side driver or library for communicating with Oracle, but there are many ways you can do this.

1) Compiling Oracle's SDK libraries directing into your application.
2) Using a locally installed SQL*Net client (which can be shared between different local applications, so that things like TNS_NAMES setup can be shared).
3) Using third-party libraries embedded in your application.

Also the different kinds of clients can expose or restrict different levels of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Oracle DB and Oracle Client on same Machine. In below order:

1. Oracle DB
2. Oracle Client

Do not forget to do an ADMIN Share prior to install Oracle DB.

To Answer the general question; You have to install Oracle Client on any machine needed to connect to the Oracle Database.